# WPF Packaging fails to include necessary 3rd party DLLs

Tags: c#, wpf, packaging

I have a WPF application that uses a third party SDK with one DLL acting as a .NET wrapper for a bunch of other DLLs written in C++ targeting Win32. The application compiles and runs fine in Debug and Release. I also created a packaging project for this application. The packaging project compiles fine and the app checker only complains about the unsafe portions of the code, as expected. When I install this package in a test machine, or run the packaging project from Visual Studio 2017 V15.9.13 the application fails to load with the exception message "FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NetWrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

I tried adding all the DLLs in the project by hand and flagged them with compile mode "resource" and "additional files" + "copy always", but the packaging app seems to ignore them. What is the correct way to pack these DLLs?, are they silently dropped off because they are unsafe code?

Comment: Have you tried to set the complie mode as **Content**?

Comment: That is the first option when you add it to the project.  Then I tried the other two options mentioned above without any change in behavior.

Comment: This has something to do with the way store Apps are installed and run. They don't go to the regular "Program Files" folder but deep in a subdirectory o "Program Files\WindowsApps\...". If I manually copy the app and what i called here "NetWrapper.DLL" for clarity, to any folder in the target computer, it runs fine.(The rest of the DLLs from the SDK are installed by a distribution pack from the vendor the same way as VCredist) when that didn't work I added all the DLLs to the project but still no luck. My next step is to port it to UWB but I'm afraid I'll be running into the same problem.